# Diffeomorphisms of circle $S^1$ ($\text{Diff}(S^1)$) and its tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am new to differential geometry and I would appreciate it if someone could help me answering these questions.

1- Why does the set of all smooth diffeomorphisms of the circle $S^1$ form a smooth manifold? I assume we need to construct local charts but the details are not so obvious to me.

2- Main question: to find a tangent vector to $\text{Diff}(S^1)$ we take a curve $\xi_t$ in $S^1$ (sequence of transformations with parameter $t$), then we have:

$\dot{\xi_t}(x) = \frac{d}{dt} \xi_t(x) = \lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{\xi_{\tau}(x) - 1}{\tau} \xi_t = u(x)\circ\xi_t(x)$

and in this book that I am reading it is mentioned that "So any tangent vector of $T_x\text{Diff}(S^1)$ is represented as $X=u(x)\partial_x$". Does the operator $\circ$ in the equation above mean normal function multiplication? And how can one deduct the form $X=u(x)\partial_x$ directly from the limit definition?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: If you're new to DG, and you're reading a book whose first example of a smooth manifold is the space of diffeomorphisms of the circle, I humbly suggest you need a new book. For someone truly new to the field, I really like Barrett O'Neil's *Elementary Differential Geometry*, which illustrates a lot of good ideas very gently in the context of surfaces in 3-space. A good next step is Millman and Parker. After that, a book that talks about more abstract spaces and examples may seem more natural, as these will appear as generalizations of familiar concepts.

Comment: I am relatively new, just trying to cover the minimal to get to the tools and theorems I need for my research. These books are great but they expand the subject too much. What I really need is a brief and to the point summaries so I can save some time.

Comment: If you are starting research in pure math, then you might have to give up on brief and to the point summaries that save time!

Comment: "expand the subject too much"? Both O'Neil and M&P are pretty much core pure differential geometry. Many folks also like DoCarmo's book, although I've never been a huge fan (but for no good reason). If this is too bog an "expansion", perhaps you can tell us what you consider the essential areas of DG so we can better help you.

Comment: Here's the trouble. You are asking questions about infinite dimensional differential geometry, when you don't yet know finite dimensional differential geometry.

Answer (score 2):

To partly answer at least your second question, the formula you typed:
$$
\dot{\xi_t}(x) = \frac{d}{dt} \xi_t(x) = \lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{\xi_{\tau}(x) - 1}{\tau} \xi_t = u(x)\circ\xi_t(x)
$$
seems to be wrong, in the sense that the types don't match for the second equality. I think it should be something akin to 
$$
\dot{\xi_t}(x) = \frac{d}{dt} \xi_t(x) = \lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{\xi_{\tau}(x) - 1}{\tau} \xi_t(x) = u(x)\circ\xi_t(x)
$$
although this requires that 
$$
\xi_a(x) \xi_b(x) =\xi_{a+b}(x)
$$
which means that the path $t \mapsto \xi_t$ has a kind of 'homomorphism' structure to it that doesn't seem to be assumed in what you've said.

It also seems to require that $\xi_\tau(x)$ be a real (or possibly complex) number, since $1$ gets subtracted from it, i.e., it assumes that $S^1$ is being treated here as the set of complex numbers of modulus 1. Alternatively, it could be that $1$ here denotes the identity function, and the proper form is 
$$
\dot{\xi_t}(x) = \frac{d}{dt} \xi_t(x) = \lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{\xi_{\tau} - 1}{\tau} (\xi_t(x)) = u(x)\circ\xi_t(x)
$$
so that the limit is a limit of *functions*, and these functions are applied to the point $\xi_t(x)$. But that doesn't seem to make sense for other reasons, like "Why should $\xi_\tau(\xi_t(x))= \xi_{t + \tau}(x)$?" That kind of statement does hold true for things like 
$$
c_a(x) = q(x + a)
$$
where $q$ is a path, and $c_a$ is the path "offset by time $a$", which often occur in "one-parameter families of geodesics", for instance...but I see nothing in what you've told us that suggests that it holds here.

I suspect that the author was trying to make the point that the thing inside the limit depends only on $x$, not $t$, but as for the meaning of the little circle, or any explanation of why this sequence of equalities is correct...I'm at a loss.

I've actually taught differential geometry two or three times in my career, perhaps not very well, and only at the undergraduate level. I took courses in it from both Singer and Chern, which gave me views of the subject from two rather different sides of things, back when I was at Berkeley. And I can't make sense of this stuff as written. Perhaps you're just a great deal more insightful than I am, and will make sense of it. But it's hard to believe that you'll do so *faster* than you can read the two other books I suggested, each of which will lead you to actually understand the basics of the subject.

Seriously: I recommend that you find a book that's more clearly written.